# jQuery smooth scroll to element - not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to make a "Click to Scroll" menu on my website (www.trianglesquad.com). I tried a code from 
 w3schools.com "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll". I am facing a problem. It doesn't scroll to perfect point. For Example, If I click on "Portfolio", It scrolls to the mid of portfolio section. It scroll to perfect point after 3-4 Clicks.
Any Help will be highly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and JS Code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping stackoverflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why all the down votes, as we all were beginners at some stage... Maybe for future posts, try creating a JS fiddle with an example and be more specific.

You can change the scrolling offset by adding or subtracting from the offset as per below example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -200
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

The key take away here is this line:

```
scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -200
```

You can add or subtract any amount of pixels that you choose.

Edit:

Actually try this code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#xp-navigation").find("a[href*=#]:not([href=#])").click(function () {
        var offset = 0;
        var speed = 1000;
        var target = $(this.hash);

        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - offset
        }, speed);
    });

});
```

It is a bit cleaner and you can also adjust the offset.